# Combine multiple identical java functions

Tags: java, android, function

Very stupid question. I'm used to php.

I am declaring multiple android MediaPlayer objects.
Based on button pressed, I want to switch between them. I currently have 3 identical functions - something like this...

```
public void playSound3() throws IOException {
     if(sound3.isPlaying()) {
        sound3.stop();
        sound3.reset();
     }
}
```

This is called with playSound3()

I'd like to combine this to be playSound(1), but can't figure out how to do it in the case of a MediaPlayer object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to refactor when only looking at one method.  You'll have to share more code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the sound in as a parameter.

```
 // Not sure what type your sound is.
public void playSound(MediaPlayer sound) throws IOException {
     if(sound.isPlaying()) {
        sound.stop();
        sound.reset();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void playSound(MediaPlayer sound) throws IOException
{
    if(sound.isPlaying())
    {
        sound.stop();
        sound.reset();
    }
}
```

then

```
playSound(sound1);
playSound(sound2);
&c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do need the parameter to be an int, you could put your MediaPlayer objects into an array :

```
public void playSound(int n) throws IOException {
    static MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayers = {sound0,sound1,sound2,sound3};

    if (n >= 0 && n < mediaPlayers.length) {
        MediaPlayer mp = mediaPlayers[n];
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface like

```
public Interface IMySoundPlayer {
    void playSound() throws IOException;
}
```

Create an array of said Interface objects and populate it

```
IMySoundPlayer[] soundPlayers = new IMySoundPlayer[] { new SoundPlayer(sound1), new SoundPlayer(sound2), new SoundPlayer(sound3) };
```

With SoundPlayer being something along the lines of

```
public class SoundPlayer implements IMySoundPlayer {
    private MediaPlayer mBackend;

    public SoundPlayer(MediaPlayer backend) {
        mBackend = backend;
    }

    public void playSound() throws IOException {
        if(mBackend.isPlaying()) {
            mBackend.stop();
            mBackend.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Rotate between the 3 instances using an integer or some other scheme and call `playSound` on each of them.

Comment if you need more guidance.

**Disclaimer**

This has been done off the top of my head, no testing (not even syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Use a list or array of some sort to store your MediaPlayer objects and then make your method take a MediaPlayer as its argument. You can then pass whichever element of the array that you need to the single method.

```
MediaPlayer[] players = {sound1, sound2, sound3};

public void playSound(MediaPlayer sound) throws IOException {
     if(sound.isPlaying()) {
         sound.stop();
         sound.reset();
     }
}

// Call method using sound1
playSound(players[0]);
```